# Possible ways to hide direct links in src attribute in audio tag? Need to mask the general directory of links

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Users downloading the audio is not a concern, it is infact a feature we provide separately.

Users can get the whole link from "Copy link/audio address" from the player link. This link is a thirdparty directory where we can not set access permission. As a result, any tech aware user can backspace and remove the filename in URL and access the whole directory which stores audio of other users.

The files are big enough that it is not feasible to store in our solution, even temporarily.

I also would prefer a codebehind solution in C# over a javascript one.

Edit: Got it working.  Put request to an aspx/ashx page in the src attribute. Serverside code in it will return stream like this:

```
    byte[] data = req.DownloadData(url);
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
    response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    response.End();
```

Comment: You could proxy the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep the knowledge of the directory on the server, not in the URL. Provide the user with something like:

```
http://yourhost.com/getaudio.aspx?fileid=324653476
```

A database maps the 324653476 to a path on the server. The audio.aspx page/handler or similar will read the bytes of the file and write them to the response stream, or do a server side instruction for the server to do the same (it won't send an http redirect to send the user to http://yourhost.com/path/to/files/abc.mp3) using HttpResponse.WriteFile, TransmitFile or similar

---

If you have no appetite for writing code to manage this, consider a reverse proxying URL rewrite instead, either on the server that serves the audio files or on an interim server. Set things up so your users can access:

```
http://yourhost.com/getaudio/abc.mp3
```

The URL rewriter shall internally rewrite this to http://yourhost.com/path/to/files/abc.mp3 and fetch it then send the bytes back to the client (don't configure it to send a redirect). The advantage is that http://yourhost.com/getaudio and doesn't match a rewrite rule, so it doesn't work out if the user tries it, and the user never gets to know the real path of the files

That said, if you could modify the config of the server to add a URL rewrite, you could modify it to deny listing the directory..

---

More simply, can you just upload a blank document with a default name (e.g. default.html, index.html) into the directory of audio files, so that anyone requesting http://yourhost.com/path/to/files/ gets the blank file served?

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the existing handler (for downloading files) in the src attribute.Some minor alterations later, working smoothly. I wasn't sure initially whether src would accept an incoming audio data in this way.